# I need a solution to overcome the error Invalid memory read from address

Tags: c, debugging

Iam working on Tessy which works on

## Compiler: Green Hills MPC

## Debugger: Green Hills MULTI 2000

Am trying to initialize a structure in memory address eg.0xf7fc0000 ,
but the multi debugger throws an error
error: [PC=0x400a9e24] Invalid memory read from address 0xf7fc0240

Can someone please guide me on how to overcome this error?

Comment: Well, do you have RAM/register at that address to which you have write permission/privilege?

Comment: I have a register at 0xf7fc0000

Comment: Please who the relevant snippets that try to access the memory address.